# How does one interpret the definition of "accretion" in galaxy formation?

Tags: galaxy, astrophysics

I am having trouble finding a solidifying definition of accretion when it comes to galaxy formation models and galaxy evolutions. Where as, in the context of satellite galaxies, dwarf galaxies, or gasses.

For example, how do interpret the sentence "Even
dwarf and Milky Way-sized halos do accrete new mass at low
redshifts".

Does this mean that they "gain" new mass or does this mean they "leak" new mass?

Comment: It means they gain new mass. I don't think I've ever seen the word accrete used to signify "leaking" mass. The official definition is "to add, as by growth."

Comment: Can you add where you got the quote from? I'd be curious to see it in more context.

Comment: @HDE226868 Sure. Its a paper detailing the splashback radius of halos and interpreting them as boundary conditions. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1504.05591.pdf